# Iframe overflowing the div

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am using a div to hold an iframe to simulate a popup window. However, the web page that the iframe loads has a drop down menu and ends up going outside the div. How do I make it so that it stay inside the div? I thought it might have been an overflow problem, but nothing I did seemed to change anything. The picture is a screenshot of what I am talking about.[image: Overflow problem]. The dropdown should stop when it gets to the darker area.

```
<head>
<style>
 #box{
        display: none;
        position:fixed;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        z-index:1001; 
        -moz-opacity: 0.4;
        opacity:.40;
        filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    }

    #popup{ 
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 35%;
        left: 40%;
        width: 1000px;
        height: 625px;
        margin: -190px 0 0 -281px;
        z-index:1002;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: white;
    }
    #popupIframe{
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        top: inherit;
        left: inherit;
        width: inherit;
        height: inherit;
        margin: -190px 0 0 -281px;
        z-index:1000;
        overflow:auto;
        background-color: white;

        }
    #over{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 3px;
    background-image: url(images/Button-Close-icon.png); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height: 32px;
    width:32px;
    z-index:1003;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id = "popup">
   <iframe id = "popupIframe"  src = "
http://quote.test.usli.com/instantquote/quote/promotion
" ></iframe> 
    <div id="over" onClick="closePopup();" > </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: create a jsfiddle, it would be easier for people to help then.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving

`overflow:none` for `#popup` div

```
#popup{ 
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 35%;
    left: 40%;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 625px;
    margin: -190px 0 0 -281px;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: none;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MmZYy/ I have never actually made a jsfiddle before so I am not sure why this doesn't work, but I copied the code directly from my web page.